# Delete content store deleted, period - cycle too long

Tags: alfresco, space

Here is the problem,

I am using Alfresco Community version 4.2.0,
Content Store Deleted stay on the server about 15 days before being really deleted...

Applications need lot of space, so, the disk gets almost full before that 15 days period reaches its end. So server finally crashes...

Is it possible to configure it to keep the files just a few days, or not at all... and how?
After few researches, I don't find any helpful information about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the time before content is deleted is set to 14 days. You can set the value of 'protectDays' in your alfresco-global.properties:

```
system.content.orphanProtectDays=2
```

Note - Don't set this to 0, it causes other issues.

Comment: Does this work with the "community" version of Alfresco?

Comment: @Julo0sS Yes, you can find more info on the community wiki: https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Store_Configuration

Comment: This has been also useful to me: https://community.alfresco.com/thread/213716-how-to-set-systemcontentorphanprotectdays-to-less-than-1-day. I also set the values `system.content.eagerOrphanCleanup=true` and `system.content.orphanCleanup.cronExpression=<A CRON>` properties.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mardoz, that solution will help you in achieving what you need but it is important to know content life cycle if you are dealing with this.

This should give you idea on everything you need.

http://blog.arvixe.com/content-lifecycle-in-alfresco/

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/clean-content.html